# embedded php code in html being displayed

Tags: php, html

i bought this php script and all the pages are in .html

when I upload it to my ubuntu server and access the site, the php codes are literally displayed along with the html....

what gives ? how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` file to have PHP process your file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Answer (score 3):

change the file extension from `.html` to `.php` =)

Comment: or tell the webserver to handle HTML as PHP in the httpdconf

Comment: yeah i did this but then i have to go back and change all the links to .php

Comment: That's maybe an hour work but it is the most normal practice as far as I know